# Why I cannot create a time series that contains E in root name of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to execute `CREATE TIMESERIES root.database.A071F.FFU.11E.11E01.run WITH DATATYPE=BOOLEAN, ENCODING=PLAIN` command in Apache IoTDB, an error was reported saying this time series cannot be created. However, when I tried `CREATE TIMESERIES root.database.A071F.FFU.11H.11H01.run WITH DATATYPE=BOOLEAN, ENCODING=PLAIN`, this error will not be reported. Is `E` in time series a keyword in IoTDB, and why did the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `11E` in Apache IoTDB, it will be identified as the scientific notation grammar, therefore if you still want to create this time series, numbers and letters need to be wrapped in backticks.